# Average-case randomized communication complexity in the small-advantage regime

Tags: lower-bounds, communication-complexity

Let $f\colon \{0, 1\}^n \times \{0, 1\}^n \to \{0, 1\}$. I'm interested in randomized communication protocols $\pi$ that compute $f$ in the weak sense that
$$
\Pr_{x, y}\left[\Pr_r[\pi(x, y, r) = f(x, y)]\geq 1/2 + \varepsilon\right] \geq 1/2 + \varepsilon,
$$
where $r$ is the internal randomness of $\pi$ and the inputs $x, y$ are sampled independently and uniformly at random from $\{0, 1\}^n$. What upper/lower bounds are known in this setting? E.g., for the inner product mod 2 function $f(x, y) = \langle x, y\rangle$, are $\Omega(n - \log(1/\varepsilon))$ bits of communication required?

Answer (score 2):

It is big open problem to prove lower bounds. This would imply lower bounds for BP.PP communication protocols (e.g., [Tarui's Theorem in communication complexity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0903)), which would then imply lower bounds on matrix rigidity (over the real numbers).

For inner product, there is $O(1)$-bit public coin protocol for $\epsilon=1/n^{O(1)}$. Let me simplify by assuming that all $x_i$ and $y_i$ are IID and get value $1$ with probability $1/\sqrt{2}$ so that $x_i=y_i=1$ with probability $1/2$. This simplifies the calculations (the uniform distribution is similar). Observe that $\langle x,y \rangle \in [0,n]$ is binomially distributed with mean $n/2$. Note that for $c\ll\sqrt{n}$ we have $\langle x,y\rangle \in n/2\pm c$ with probability $\Theta(c/\sqrt{n})$.

For warm up, consider the following protocol: Sample random $i\in[n]$ and accept if $x_i=y_i=1$. Assuming $n$ is odd, $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ is even and $\lceil n/2\rceil$ is odd, this protocol guesses $IP(x,y)$ right (with advantage $\approx 1/n$) whenever $\langle x,y\rangle \in \{\lfloor n/2\rfloor,\lceil n/2\rceil\}$, which occurs with probability $\Theta(1/\sqrt{n})$ over $(x,y)$.

More generally, using the connection between small-advantage computations (class PP) and low-degree polynomials approximating Xor for inputs of Hamming weight $n/2\pm c$ (e.g, [The expressive power of voting polynomials](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/papers/stoc91voting.pdf)) there are $O(c)$-bit protocols that guess $IP(x,y)$ right (with advantage $1/n^{O(c)}$) when $\langle x,y\rangle \in n/2 \pm c$.

When $\langle x,y\rangle$ is outside middle interval, $\langle x,y\rangle \notin n/2 \pm c$, we expect the protocol to err on roughly half the inputs $(x,y)$. Choosing a large enough constant $c$, the correctness in the middle interval starts dominating: protocol guesses right with probability $1/2+\Theta(c/\sqrt{n})$ over $(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The protocol for inner product doesn't seem correct to me though. E.g., consider $n=3$. With respect to the protocol's internal randomness, the success probability is $1$ when $\langle x, y \rangle \in \{0, 3\}$, and the success probability is $1/3$ when $\langle x, y \rangle \in \{1, 2\}$. Therefore, the probability of getting good inputs $(x, y)$ is $(3/4)^3 + (1/4)^3 < 1/2$, so the protocol doesn't work. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry I was sloppy. I added details